# Método pausar a contagem regressiva

Tags: android

Boa noite, fiz uma contagem regressiva no meu aplicativo com o botão de play para poder iniciar a contagem.... só que queria fazer um método de pausar o tempo e quando clicasse no botão play de novo ele continuava de onde parou... como poderei fazer isso?

segue meu código abaixo:

class do tempo:

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Tempo extends CountDownTimer {

    private View.OnClickListener context;
    private TextView tv;
    private long tempao;


    public Tempo(View.OnClickListener context, TextView tv, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

        this.context = context;
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tempao = millisUntilFinished;
        tv.setText(getCorretcTimer(true, millisUntilFinished)+":"+getCorretcTimer(false, millisUntilFinished));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tempao -= 1000;
        tv.setText(getCorretcTimer(true, tempao)+":"+getCorretcTimer(false, tempao));

        Toast.makeText((Context) context, "Fim de jogo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    private String getCorretcTimer(boolean isMinute, long millisInFuture){
        String aux;
        int calen = isMinute ? Calendar.MINUTE : Calendar.SECOND;
        Calendar cc = Calendar.getInstance();
        cc.setTimeInMillis(millisInFuture);
        aux = cc.get(calen) < 10 ? "0"+cc.get(calen) : ""+cc.get(calen);
        return (aux);
    }
}
```

código da Activity:

```
public class SimplesHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgButton_play, imgButton_pause, imgButton_1, imgButton_2, vermlho, amarelo;
    public TextView valorOne, valorDouble, hora;
    public int contador = 0;
    public int contador1 = 0;
    private Chronometer reloginho;
    private EditText casa, fora;
    long tempoPausado = 0;
    private Tempo time;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simples);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        imgButton_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_1);
        imgButton_2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_2);
        vermlho = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVermelho);
        amarelo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAmarelo);
        imgButton_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_play);
        imgButton_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_pause);
        reloginho = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        valorOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor1);
        valorDouble = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor2);
        casa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time1);
        fora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time2);
        hora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTempo);


        imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
        imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);

        imgButton_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(true);


                time = new Tempo(this, hora, 9901*1000, 1000);
                time.start();


                Context ini = getApplication();
                CharSequence iniciar = "Partida iniciada";
                int mostrar = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast ir = Toast.makeText(ini, iniciar, mostrar);
                ir.show();
            }
        });

        imgButton_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);

                Context parar = getApplication();
                CharSequence frase = "Partida pausada";
                int rele = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast stop = Toast.makeText(parar, frase, rele);
                stop.show();
            }
        });
      }
   }
```

Obrigado....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta você criar uma variável do tipo booleana (bool) `pausado`, inicialmente com valor atribuido como `false`.

Adicionar ao Botão `Pause`, para definir a variável `pausado` como `true`. Definir o Botão `Play`, para definir a variável `pausado` como `false`,  e na ação de decrementar o valor, basta adicionar adicionar uma condição, para decrementar apenas se não estiver pausado, exemplo:

```
if(!pausado)
{
    tempo--;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, em caso de erros basta deixar um comentário.

Comment: então amigo... fiz dessa forma:`time.cancel();`ele até para... mas parece que ele não armazena o valor para poder continuar de onde parou... se eu seguir a minha logica como poderia fazer?

Comment: No caso, ao clicar novamente em `Play` ele reinicia do zero?

Comment: Sim... queria que ele começasse de onde parou sabe?

Comment: O que está acontecendo, é que ao clicar em `Play`, ele seta o tempo novamente `time = new Tempo(this, hora, 9901*1000, 1000);
                time.start();`, você pode seta-lo em outro local, ou criar uma restrição para caso o `time` esteja zerado, ele setar o tempo novamente.

Comment: seguindo essa logica, como que eu faço?

Comment: Vamos fazer diferente, achei uma forma mais facil, no Botão `Pause` coloque `tempoPausado = !tempoPausado`, obs.: Altere a variável `tempoPausado` para booleana, e no decrementar coloque a condição, como disse acima... Para pausar pressione o botão `Pause` e para despausar, bastará pressiona-lo novamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48252/discussion-between-vitor-subhi-and-nathan).